# Comment parsing bug turns '/' into '7;'

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Something's fishy with the comment parsing. Watch:

Before:

[image: Comment source code]

After

[image: Comment as rendered]

Affected question: [Python Changing value of XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170181/python-changing-value-of-xml)

Comment: What happens when you paste that tag into notepad? I get something I can't actually paste in a comment but it looks like a superscript backwards L.

Comment: [Can confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152404/maven-not-including-manifest-attributes-for-lwjgl-install/39153356?noredirect=1#comment65651635_39153356) <- this is a comment of mine from yesterday, notice the `<‌​7;source>`. Test `<files><file><source>${project.build.directory}/${projec‌​t.finalName}.jar</source><outputDire‌​ctory>/</out‌​putDirectory></f‌​ile></files>` <- it does it also on Meta.

Comment: Does it only occur when adding the HTML entity?  That seems like the smoking gun here.

Comment: `<‌​/source>` `/not html`

Comment: `glob('/Users/eeamesX/work/data/expert‌​/EFTlogs/201607‌​25/IT/*.xml'‌​)`

Comment: glob('/Users/eeamesX/work/data/expert‌​/EFTlogs/201607‌​25/IT/*.xml'‌​)

Comment: Looks like it happens when it is marked as inline code.  regex must still have a bug in it

Comment: Will be fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283888/323179

Comment: @Laurel this looks like the same issue. Maybe this thread can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Tomalak :P That's not possible, since it's MSE, and this is MSO.

Comment: Looks like it is fixed now. The problem doesn't appear on the above comments anymore.

Comment: ///////////////